# How to install Ubuntu in Android Tablet? Can I remove the Android OS from the EEE Pad transformer?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I bought Android Asus EEE Pad Transformer and I don't like this OS. It's all hidden how Linux should be.

How do you remove the existing OS, there is no jack such as USB nor it has any boot menu nor it has BIOS it just after power on. It shows Android.

Any idea how to install in this now? (e.g: [how to root your Asus EEE pad transformer](http://android.modaco.com/topic/337190-14-apr-how-to-root-your-asus-eee-pad-transformer/))

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/182579/can-i-replace-the-android-os-with-ubuntu-on-the-zeki-7-0-android-tablet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at [How to install Ubuntu on an Asus EEEPad Transformer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/How_to_install_Ubuntu_on_an_Asus_EEEPad_Transformer).

However, this is not really a question for Ask Ubuntu. The method of doing this is experimental, fast changing and is not suitable for Ask Ubuntu. The wiki article was only created this month.

Also see [Ubuntu on the Transformer (eMMC install)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1191141) and [Ubuntu on the transformer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1280774).

Comment: It seems like a perfectly valid question to me. What is wrong with it?