# Can I replace the Android OS with Ubuntu on the Zeki 7.0" Android Tablet?

Tags: android, tablet, ubuntu-touch

I just ordered [this tablet](http://www.target.com/p/zeki-7-android-tablet-tb782b-with-8gb-internal-storage-1gb-memory-black/-/A-14190620) from Target, but I would much rather have Ubuntu on it than Android. Is there any way I can remove Android and install Ubuntu with the necessary drivers? It seems like it should be possible, but I have never heard of it being done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can download an ARM image at cdimage.ubuntu.com. See http://www.ubuntu.com/download/arm

1. Download the images at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.1
2. Place the SD card at your host computer.
3. Make sure the SD card is not mounted (just `umount` it if needed)
4. Identify the correct raw device name (like `/dev/sde` - not `/dev/sde1`)
   Run the following command to write it: 
   (replacing omap4 and sde with the right values i.e. just omap for a beagle image.)

   zcat ./ubuntu-12.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+omap4.img.gz |sudo dd bs=4M of=/dev/sde ; sudo sync

Warning /!\ Some people have reported issues with this method. If this doesn't work, try the following commands:
2. `gunzip ubuntu-12.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+omap4.img.gz`
3. `sudo dd bs=4M if=ubuntu-12.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+omap4.img of=/dev/sde`
4. `sudo sync`

Comment: I'm pretty new to this--can you tell me how that works?

Comment: Wait while I add the instructions

Comment: OK thanks, one more question: if this doesn't work or if I don't like it, is there any way to do a factory reset?

Comment: I don't know actually. I'm not a great guy at Android

Comment: OK, no problem.

Answer (score 4):

ok, you *wont* be able to do a factory reset because all it does is format the data and cache partitions and leaves boot and system intact...

you will need to have a backup of the android rom or dump it, then you will need to reflash it.

BTW: i really doubt that image would have all the drivers for your specific hardware.
a safer way that can be easily be reversed would be using the chroot method.

there are frontends that can do all this for you, such as "complete linux installer" or "linux deploy"

remember GIYF