# Ubuntu on galaxy note II

Tags: smartphone

I recently bought Samsung Galaxy Note II on android 4.1. 
It was my idea to try to turn it into a pc and I bought a micro-keyboard for the same purpose. I had hoped there would be an app for OpenOffice, but there isn't. Now i see that ubuntu may be installed on smart phones. I already have ubuntu - including OpenOffice - on my laptop. 
My question is: is it possible to install ubuntu to galaxy note II, and if so, does it include office programs and other ubuntu programs?

Thank You

And thank you so much for an alternative to Microsoft.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/182579/can-i-replace-the-android-os-with-ubuntu-on-the-zeki-7-0-android-tablet/182582#182582

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu NoRoot is an app available for Android phones.

> This app will install Debian or Ubuntu onto your device.
>   You will need a mouse or stylus to use it.
>
> This app is **NOT full Ubuntu OS** - it is a compatibility layer, which allows you to run Ubuntu applications. **This is NOT official Ubuntu.com release**.

You can keep both OS the full version take 1.5 to 2 GB space you can download it from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cuntubuntu&feature=search_result).