# Can I run Ubuntu OS on a Android 4.0 tablet?

Tags: android, touchscreen, tablet

I have a cheap Chinese made tablet from Dubai called the Crony Dubai (www.cronydubai.com). It has a micro B, mini HDMI and a USB labeled as "Host" as well as a micro SD slot. It came with a micro B to USB adapter in box, and its running Ice Cream Sandwich. Is there a way to load Ubuntu on it? Also the tablet is very buggy and crashes often, would that be due to the tablet or the OS?

Comment: At your own risk you may try to do what's described here if the SoC on your tablet is compatible: http://askubuntu.com/questions/182579/can-i-replace-the-android-os-with-ubuntu-on-the-zeki-7-0-android-tablet?lq=1 , Else if you have access to the play store search for an app to install Ubuntu (there are plenty).

Comment: @UriHerrera, please explain what a SoC is.

Comment: @guntbert [A system on a chip or system on chip (SoC or SOC) is an integrated circuit (IC) that integrates all components of a computer or other electronic system into a single chip.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_chip) or in this case known as the Tablet's Processor.

Comment: If the CPU in the tablet are too old version of arm, if that is the CPU type in it, you might try another distribution, like Debian. Debian support many more different types of CPUs than Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you are looking for something like **Ubuntu for Android**.

- http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android

Canonical is also working on a **Ubuntu for Phones** (including tablets) which is going to be available for download anytime soon

- http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone
- [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)
- [When is Ubuntu Phone/Touch coming to the U.S.?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574932/when-is-ubuntu-phone-touch-coming-to-the-u-s)

its all work in progress though and it does not guarantee that it will work on your tablet.

Neither of those solutions are available to the public yet! and the first one is explicitly is for OEMs (thanks to Uri Herrera for pointing it out).

Comment: But I'm not sure if its a hardware issue, I think it may be android

Comment: then check the links and give it a try, or use the method mentioned by Anam Ahmed, his Solution runs an emulator though.

Comment: Neither the first or the second suggested options are available to the public, the  first explicitly is for OEMs. The second hasn't been released yet and it's not desktop Ubuntu is it's mobile counterpart that so far only runs on the Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: thats why i said "its all work in progress" and "it doesn'guarantee that it WILL work on his tablet", but you are right, I might edit it to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of running Ubuntu on Android tablet. therefore you can go for the safest way:

1. Download [Limbo PC Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.max2idea.android.limbo.main&hl=en)
2. Create a virtual PC
3. Download [Ubuntu minimal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)
4. Install Ubuntu minimal on the virtual machine with the command line interface. More here on [Ubuntu help - Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation).

You should be up and running. This worked on my Ainol Novo 7 Crystal.