# When is Ubuntu Phone/Touch coming to the U.S.?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, smartphone

Does anyone know when it's coming to the U.S.!? The UI looks beautiful and I've been waiting to get it. I feel like we've been waiting forever.

Also did they mention how it will work? Do you have to buy a phone with it already installed on it or will we be able to download and install it on any Android phone like we can download the desktop version of Ubuntu on any Windows PC?

Comment: // , Good question! Many users are more familiar with the idea of an "Ubuntuphone" than the idea of installing Ubuntu on a phone without it.

Comment: // , Would you be willing to make this more specific, @Joel, and perhaps add some details about where the phone is at the moment?

Answer (score 4):

There are hints of a new manufacturer that will make it available to the U.S. Who, what, and actually when is anyone's guess.

Source:
Check out @omgubuntu's Tweet: https://twitter.com/omgubuntu/status/565596316622147585?s=09

If you want a retail everyday phone, it would be best to buy one from a manufacturer preinstalled. However if you are a developer, there are supported images for Nexus 4, and community images for the Nexus 5. Most of the other community ports have fallen behind.

And no, because of the complexity of how the drivers work for phones, there needs to be separate images for every device.

*Even you buy one of the currently selling BQ phones, it will not work with 3G or 4G speeds, so as a consumer in the U.S. don't try to get one now. It seems you can now get these shipped to the US.*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is up your alley or not, but it looks like its possible to install it right now with a bit of effort. I havent tried since I am but a novice, but maybe if you've got an old phone it would work out?

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/