# Misc. Q's for installing Ubuntu Phone/Tablet on the Galaxy S5

Tags: system-installation, android

I want to install Ubuntu on my Galaxy S5 with 16 GB and I had many things that are way over my head:
     -Can It be dual booted?
-Is it possible to boot from the micro-sd card slot?
     -Is it possible to install ubuntustudio?
     -How can the warranty be retained?
     -What software is available for calling/texting through Verizon's network?
-What would make more sense to install: Ubuntu Phone or Ubuntu Tablet?
Answers to any of these questions are greatly appreciated  :)

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my questions, though does have some interesting info.

Comment: [Dual-Boot Android, Ubuntu Touch Or Firefox OS On Nexus 4 & 7 With MultiROM](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/dual-boot-android-ubuntu-touch-or-firefox-os-on-nexus-4-7-with-multirom/) (Disclaimer: Please follow this guide at your own risk.) I have an answer to the last question on your list in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/574932/when-is-ubuntu-phone-touch-coming-to-the-u-s/574976#574976).

Comment: We're sorry, but your question is too broad to answer in the limited space we have here...  Please try [edit]ing your answer to better use our format or split up your question in multiple questions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure how to make this less broad without not asking some of my questions (the purpose of this site is to answer them, right?). I was not aware that this site was running out of space, though I feel as though splitting this up into multiple questions would not help that problem. If I'm wrong, (with more questions taking up less space) tell me. In the meantime, I'll look back over the question I was marked as a duplicate of to make sure some of my sub-questions haven't already been answered. Thanks!